# Searching for sub-strings in mysql

Tags: mysql, string

I know that if I were to search for a substring in a mysql cell, I can do something like the following

```
Select * from table_name where column_name like '%search_string%';
```

How do I perform the search if the cell values are the search strings? For example, if I have the following table,

```
ID  String
1    abc
2    def
3    ghi
```

And I have the string "123abc567", I want to be able to search the table so I get the result ID = 1. What mysql statement should I use, or do I have to read row by row and then do a strstr() in my program?

Comment: How is this `c++` related?

Comment: Could you please clarify: You have the string "123abc567" *outside* of the database and want to search your table for columns containing a substring of it? Or your table contains "123abc567"?

Comment: Yes, I have a string "123abc456" outside of the database. Thanks @WojciechFrohmberg for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it pretty much similarly:

```
select * from table_name where '123abc456' like concat('%', column_name, '%');
```

see an example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0fce/1/0

PS. remove the `c++` tag because it's unrelated...